# R: Get index of first instance in vector greater than variable but for whole colum

Tags: r, loops, data.table, match, sequencing

I am trying to create a new variable in a data.table. It is intended to take a variable in the data.table and for each observation compare that variable to a vector and return the index of the first observation in the vector that is greater than the variable in the data.table.

**Example**

```
ComparatorVector <- c(seq(1000, 200000, 1000))
Variable <- runif(10, min = 1000, max = 200000)
```

For each observation in `Variable` I'd like to know the index of the first observation in `ComparatorVector` that is larger than the observation of `Variable`.

I've played araound with `min(which())`, but couldn't get it to just go through the `ComparatorVector`. I also saw the `match()` function, but didn't find how to get it to return anything but the index of the exact match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is `findInterval`

```
findInterval(Variable, ComparatorVector) +1
#[1] 190 152  99 107  38 148 114  95  53  73
```

---

Or with `sapply`

```
sapply(Variable, function(x) which(ComparatorVector > x)[1])
#[1] 190 152  99 107  38 148 114  95  53  73
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Any suggestions on how to handle variables that are above the last variable in the ComparatorVector?

Comment: @user9504090 i didn't get your question.  I was trying to answer the question based on the description in the post.

Comment: Yup. You're right. What you have provided should work. My data is just not limited to the highest value ComparatorVector and I was wondering how to deal with observations that are above that value, but could then just redefine the NA outputs.

Comment: @user9504090 you could `replace` with `NA` as I am still not clear about the logic you wanted to implement

Comment: My data (what I called `Variable` above) actually contains observations that are greater than 200000 (the upper limit I defined in `ComparatorVector` above). I was just wondering how to deal with the results of your approach for these cases. However, as you said and I also realized: The solution should just be to replace the results of your approach that are NA.

Comment: @user9504090 For easiness, I would use a small example for crosschecking